# Not able to get the output of my Rest Webservices and it is getting HTTP 404 exception

Tags: java, rest, web-services, tomcat

In the time of executing this program, I am getting HTTP Status 404 exception:

> HTTP Status 404 - /Restful_WebServices_Tuts/test/home
>   type Status report
>   message /Restful_WebServices_Tuts/test/home
>   description The requested resource is not available.
>   Apache Tomcat/8.0.36

This my app class

```
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("/test")
public class JAX_RS_Starter extends Application{

}
```

This is my Hello world class using the GET annotation

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import java.lang.String;


@Path("/hello")
public class HelloRS{
    @GET
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String HelloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

And my Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Restful WebServices Tuts</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: `/home` where did you declared ?

Comment: sorry it is hello.. i mentioned as home.. but even now i tried with hello also... same error is getting

Answer (score 0):

What's in your Web-Inf\web.xml?

Usually there's a `<servlet-mapping>` that contains a `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>`

That got to be chained in url, so, supposing you're on local environment with 8080 port and set a specific PATH for your webmethod like:

```
@GET
@Path("getHelloTest")
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public String HelloWorld(){
```

You could have:

```
http://localhost:8080/YourProjectName/rest/hello/getHelloTest
```

If you have declared a context menu like "/", you can exclude the project name from rest uri.

Comment: sorry, but i can't understand.. can you please clear me what i have to change in my code.. and Port 8080 is currently SQL is using so i am not able to use the same for Apache server.. so i am using 8083

Comment: Hii Web.xml is added.. can you please check once

Comment: That web.xml doesn't specify rest rules to try exclude /Restful_WebServices_Tuts (supposing its project name) from URL.

Comment: yes jacj, that is a project name.. is it possible to exclude and execute with out the project name

Answer (score 0):

**Which Framework you used ?**

Please try this if your server port number is 8080

http://localhost:8080/Restful_WebServices_Tuts/test

and If you r using Liferay framework try this

http://localhost:8080/o/Restful_WebServices_Tuts/test

I hope you find your mistakes.
Hope it helps.